# how to update openssh server only selected version?

Tags: linux, debian, openssh

my version openssh-server is

> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3

how i update to version 7.2p2??

Comment: You're on debian, so probably using `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`. If it's not available there, it's probably not advisable to update it in any other way. If you're using a supported Debian version, that's not a security problem, as debian is pretty good about security backports.

Answer (score 2):

Debian 8 has been out of even long-term support [since June 2020](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/); there are no updates for it. You should upgrade to at least Debian 10, which is [the oldest currently-supported release of Debian](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/). Debian 10 includes OpenSSH 7.9p1.

When upgrading from Debian 8 to Debian 10, you should upgrade to Debian 9 first; make sure to read the release notes for both [Debian 9](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/releasenotes) and [Debian 10](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/releasenotes).

(If you’re trying to upgrade because of specific security concerns, note that your version of OpenSSH is outdated even with reference to Debian 8 — there were [a](https://tracker.debian.org/news/887963/accepted-openssh-167p1-5deb8u4-source-amd64-all-into-oldstable-proposed-updates-oldstable-new-oldstable-proposed-updates/) [few](https://tracker.debian.org/news/981607/accepted-openssh-167p1-5deb8u5-source-amd64-all-into-oldstable/) [updates](https://tracker.debian.org/news/986365/accepted-openssh-167p1-5deb8u6-source-amd64-all-into-oldstable/) [after](https://tracker.debian.org/news/986981/accepted-openssh-167p1-5deb8u7-source-amd64-all-into-oldstable/) the version you have. You can install these with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, but you may run into issues caused by expired signatures.)